# .NET Framework 4.7.2 Upgrade - The project file could not be loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, upgrade, .net-framework-version

I just went through every project in the solution and upgraded from .NET Framework 4.6.1 => 4.7.2 and only one project cannot be loaded. When I try to reload the project, it throws this error:

```
3:07 PM Project 'MyProject' load finished with warnings: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. at (1:1)

3:07 PM Project 'MyProjectEmailService' load failed: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.  C:\Projects\Repo\Source\MyProject\MyProjectEmailService\MyProjectEmailService.csproj at (1:1)

3:07 PM Project 'MyProjectEmailService.Tests' load finished with warnings: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. at (1:1)

3:07 PM Project 'MyProjectEmailService.Tests' load finished with warnings: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. at (1:1)

3:08 PM Project 'MyProjectEmailService' load failed: The project file could not be loaded. The 'Project' start tag on line 2 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'Target'. Line 281, position 5.  C:\Projects\Repo\Source\MyProject\MyProjectEmailService\MyProjectEmailService.csproj at (281:5)

3:09 PM Project 'MyProjectEmailService' load failed: The project file could not be loaded. The 'Project' start tag on line 2 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'Target'. Line 281, position 5.  C:\Projects\Repo\Source\MyProject\MyProjectEmailService\MyProjectEmailService.csproj at (281:5)
```

From what I can tell, it appears that there is something wrong with line 281 in the `MyProjectEmailService.csproj`

On line 281, I find `</target>`

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\OctoPack.3.6.1\build\OctoPack.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\OctoPack.3.6.1\build\OctoPack.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.23.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.23.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.0.24.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.0.24.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\OctoPack.3.6.1\build\OctoPack.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\OctoPack.3.6.1\build\OctoPack.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.23.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.23.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.0.24.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.0.24.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.targets')" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Here's the first lines of the `csproj` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
```

How can I fix this and get my project to load properly? Also, just let me know if you need more information.

Comment: seems You have unnecessary </Target> . Check opening and closing of those tags

Comment: *"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1"* That means the very beginning of the file. Please show that part. Errors later in the file, especially missing/expected closing tags, can be caused by the errors at the start of the file. Something got corrupted. Do you have a backup (read: source control) against which you can compare the changes?

Comment: @madreflection I added the first couple lines

Comment: @madreflection I do have access to source control. I wonder if it's missing that weird UNICODE character that starts the file

Comment: The BOM. That shouldn't be necessary, though. You have `encoding="utf-8"` in the XML declaration. That should be enough to detect the encoding of an XML file.

Comment: Hi Kolob, any update for this issue? What's the result if we remove the extra tag. If the issue persists, please feel free to let me know with more details and error message:)

Comment: Hi Kolob, is this issue solved or not? If you get the detailed solution or useful steps in your side, you could share it as the answer, so it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i think **Prateek** has located the cause of the issue.

The correct format of the content you shared above should be like:

```
<Project...>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\OctoPack.3.6.1\build\OctoPack.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\OctoPack.3.6.1\build\OctoPack.targets'))" />
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.23.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.23.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets'))" />
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.0.24.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.0.24.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.targets'))" />

  </Target> //**This line is where the error occurs**

  <Import Project="..\..\packages\OctoPack.3.6.1\build\OctoPack.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\OctoPack.3.6.1\build\OctoPack.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.23.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.23.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.0.24.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.0.24.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.targets')" />

  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Now it's clear you have an extra `</Target>`, I assume you may have a custom target before the upgrade, and delete the target after your upgrade. But accidentally forget to delete the end tag of it.

**Solution:**

So I think deleting the `</Target>`  line can help resolve this issue.

And this issue is reproducible, create a new console project in VS, unload it and add a  line into it then similar issue happens when you click reload button:

[image]

Just be careful when modifying the project files.